# Custom colors for shell

Tags: bash, shell, colors, zsh

How do you customise the default colours in the shell? Say I want to make the standard cyan, magenta and yellow slightly lighter.

There is a method shown [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/55088/2007/01/termcolor.html) for OS X Terminal using drag and drop with the colour picker, but how do you do it manually in the dotfiles (.bashrc .bash_profile .zshrc etc)?

Comment: You should write which terminal client you use.

Comment: Well, I am using OS X Terminal, but I want to make my prefs portable via a dotfiles repo like this http://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles/tree/master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash has nothing to do with it. The way colors are is depending on your terminal. If you're using OS X Terminal - you have to use its way to configure colors.

Answer (score 3):

Check into creating a .Xdefaults file on your home directory.

Here is a good .Xdefaults syntax guide:
http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdefaults#Xdefaults_syntax

A snippet of my own .Xdefaults:

Xterm*background:        wheat

Xterm*foreground:        black
Xterm*scrollBar_right:   true

Xterm*scrollTtyKeypress  true
Xterm*colorBD:           1

Xterm*font:              courier
Xterm*saveLines:         10000

Xterm*geometry:          120x50

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do with bash alone is to have a [different color on your prompt](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt) on different computers/accounts.

My prompt is red when I'm root for example.